# div in front of another resets jQuery hover animation. how to prevent this?

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-animate, html

i have an animate effect applied to 4 divs in order to create a blinds effect: when you hover over the first box it grows , the other 3 shrink and when you "mouseout" all 4 return to 25% of the total height.

i want to insert a nested div inside each box (in front, actually with absolute positioning) in order to present some text and links, but every time the mouse hovers over this new div, the animation resets (the mouseout event runs).

how can i make the nested div invisible to the animation? or include it such way that it is invisible to the animation code but the urls work properly?

the example is here:

[jquery problem](http://maucreative.com/css_tests/test_demo.html)

all code is inline for this demo.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, check [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/y8nwW/)

The trick to add the selector `$("#one > *")`

Comment: Wow! That was FAST! I thought I could go to sleep and work in the morning. Thanx Starx! :)

Comment: Starx, I noticed the "mouseout" property is no longer working, i.e, the boxes won't return to their initial 25% height. I'm looking for some documentation in http://jquery.com/ for the trick you showd me. Does it have a specific name? I thought it had something to do with .children, but I guess it doesn't. Thanx again.

Comment: I have improved the coding you used, check it out http://www.jsfiddle.net/y8nwW/1/

Comment: Thanx, I'll check it. All the best.

Comment: It's still a little jittery, but you've pointed me in the right direction. Thank you so much for your help, Starx.